# relocate apache's configuration files

Tags: apache, apache-config

is there a chance to use different location for apache's config files (on Windows)? Other than having to compile it myself and setting the proper #define HTTPD_ROOT value.

Thx rezna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by specifying the `-f` option when installing apache as a service on Windows.

The `-f` option accepts the location of the configuration file.  For example, if your command to install the service was

```
httpd.exe -k install -n "MyServiceName"
```

Add `-f "c:\files\my.conf"`, with your configuration file instead, like so:

```
httpd.exe -k install -n "MyServiceName" -f "c:\files\my.conf"
```

See the [Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html#winsvc) for more information.